# Query decendants in XML to Linq

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have the following xml data:

```
<portfolio>
  <item>
    <title>Site</title>
    <description>Site.com is a </description>
    <url>http://www.site.com</url>
    <photos>
      <photo url="http://www.site.com/site/thumbnail.png" thumbnail="true" description="Main" />
      <photo url="http://www.site.com/site/1.png" thumbnail="false" description="Main" />
    </photos>
  </item>  
</portfolio>
```

In c# I am using the following link query:

```
List<PortfolioItem> list = new List<PortfolioItem>();
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/app_data/portfolio.xml"));

list = (from portfolio in xmlDoc.Descendants("item")
       select new PortfolioItem()
       {
           Title = portfolio.Element("title").Value,
           Description = portfolio.Element("description").Value,
           Url = portfolio.Element("url").Value
       }).ToList();
```

How do I go about querying the photos node? In the PortfolioItem class I have a property:

`List<Photo> Photos {get;set;}`

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm making some assumptions about your *photo* class, assuming for the sake of this answer that you would initialize url in the constructor, and the other two by their properties.

The most straightforward way is just to consider *Photos* one more property to return in your mail linq query, and create it with a simple sub-query.

```
    list = (from portfolio in xmlDoc.Descendants("item")
            select new PortfolioItem()
           {
               Title = portfolio.Element("title").Value,
               Description = portfolio.Element("description").Value,
               Url = portfolio.Element("url").Value,
               Photos = (From P In portfilio.Element("photos").Elements("photo")
                   Select new Photo(P.Attribute("url").Value)
                       {
                           .Thumbnail = bool.Parse(P.Attribute("thumbnail").Value),
                           .Description = P.Attribute("description").Value
                       }).ToList()
           }).ToList();
```

A good opportunity to check out the concept of [closures](http://devpinoy.org/blogs/jakelite/archive/2007/12/17/closures-in-linq.aspx) in LINQ if you haven't already.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your Photo class looks like this:

```
class Photo
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public bool Thumbnail { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

You can do it like this:

```
list = (from portfolio in xmlDoc.Descendants("item")
        select new PortfolioItem()
        {
            Title = portfolio.Element("title").Value,
            Description = portfolio.Element("description").Value,
            Url = portfolio.Element("url").Value,
            Photos = portfolio
                         .Element("photos")
                         .Elements("photo")
                         .Select(e => new Photo {
                             Description = e.Attribute("description").Value,
                             Url = e.Attribute("url").Value,
                             Thumbnail = bool.Parse(e.Attribute("thumbnail").Value),
                         }).ToList()
        }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not as fast as the others but again something very similar:

If your PortfolioItem and Photo classes look like this:

```
    public class PortfolioItem
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public List<Photo> Photos { get; set; }
    }

    public class Photo
    {
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string thumbnail { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
    }
```

Then query the photos node and populate the Photos List like so:

```
    var list = (from portfolio in xmlDoc.Descendants("item")
     select new PortfolioItem()
           {
                    Title = portfolio.Element("title").Value,
                    Description = portfolio.Element("description").Value,
                    Url = portfolio.Element("url").Value,
                    Photos = portfolio.Elements("photos")
                             .Elements("photo")
                             .Select(p => new Photo {
                              url = p.Attribute("url").Value,
                              thumbnail = p.Attribute("thumbnail").Value,
                              description = p.Attribute("description").Value
                              }).ToList()
                     }).ToList();
```